# Can I create a initial object for any finite set, signature and set of equations?

Tags: abstract-algebra

$(\mathbb{N}, 0, s)$ has the following Universal Property:

Given $(A, a, f)$, where $A$ is any set, $a \in A$ and $f:A \rightarrow A$ a function, there exists a unique function $\phi: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$ such that $\phi(0) = a$ and $\phi \circ s = f \circ \phi$

Let $F$ be the free group on the letters $a, b$. It has the following Universal Property:

$\{a, b\} \subseteq F$, there exists a distinguished element $e \in F$, there exists a unary operator $^{-1}: F \rightarrow F$ and a binary operator $\times: F \times F \rightarrow F$ such that the following equalities hold:

1. $xe = ex = x$ for all $x \in F$
2. $x{x}^{-1} = x^{-1}x = e$ for all $x \in F$
3. $x(yz) = (xy)z$ for all $x, y, z \in F$

Furthermore, if $(G, \{g, h\}, e_G, ^{-1}, \times_{G})$ satisfies the three equalities above, then there exists a unique function $\psi: F \rightarrow G$ such that $\psi(a) = g$, $\psi(b) = h$, $\psi(e) = e_G$, $\psi(x^{-1}) = {\psi(x)}^{-1}$, $\psi(xy) = \psi(x)\psi(y)$.

Can this result be generalized? I mean, let's say I have $(a_1, \dots, a_k, \phi_1, \dots, \phi_m, w_1 = w^\prime_1, \dots, w_n = w^\prime_m)$ where $a_1, \dots, a_k$ are finitely many letters, $\phi_1, \phi_2, \dots, \phi_m$ are operators of arbitrary arities, and $w_1 = w^\prime_1, \dots, w_2 = w_n = w^\prime_m$ are finitely many equations. Can I construct a set $I$ such that $a_1, \dots, a_k \in I$, all the equation $w_1 = w^\prime_1, \dots, w_2 = w_m = w^\prime_m$ are satisfied, and for any set $S$ containing distinguished elements $s_1, \dots, s_k \in S$ operators $\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_m$ with the same arities as the operators $\phi_1, \dots, \phi_m$ , and satisfying all the equations $w_1 = w^\prime_1, \dots, w_2 = w_m = w^\prime_m$; there exists a unique morphism $\pi: I \rightarrow S$ that is "structure preserving"

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do this by starting with all constant symbols, freely applying all operations, then quotienting by all equations.

Comment: Yes, free objects exist in any equationally defined class of $\Omega$-algebras. The magic words you are looking for are “Universal Algebra” (or “General Algebra”) for the subject matter, and “Variety” (for an equationally defined class of algebras of a given signature). I recommend George Bergman’s [An Invitation to General Algebra and Universal Constructions](https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/245/). That said, this is a slightly different situation than the natural numbers and the recursion theorem.

Comment: Bergman provides three different ways to construct the free group, and it should be clear how to adapt the  the definition as “subgroup of a big enough product” to the arbitrary setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is always possible when one is dealing with an "equational theory".

To be precise, this means that one has a first-order theory consisting entirely of function symbols, together with "equational axioms" - that is, axioms containing only universal quantifiers and equality as logical symbols.

The fact that this can be done in general is a consequence of the Adjoint Functor Theorem.

Note, however, that this is not always possible when one introduces non-equational axioms. For example, the theory of fields has no initial object. This is because that field would have to map into $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and would thus have a characteristic of both 2 and 3.

Comment: I am interested in the Adjoint Functor Theorem. Is there any introductory book that teaches this theorem and "similarly spirited" results?

Comment: @Lucas: Bergman's book does.

Comment: @Magidin: Thank you for the suggestion, I will try to see if I can access his book.